# Limit of probability of intersection of infinite sets

Tags: probability-theory

For a sequence of set $\{A_n\}$ with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n)=1$, define $B_n:=\cap_{k=n}^{n+c_n}A_n.$ For the case $c_n$ is a fixed integer, it is easy to see that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(B_n)=1$ still holds. For the case  where $c_n$ satisfies $c_n\rightarrow\infty$ and $c_n/n\rightarrow0$, What is the limiting probability of $B_n$? My guess is that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(B_n)=1$ doesnot hold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(A_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence of independent events such that $\mathbb P\left(A_n\right)=\exp\left(-\delta_N\right)$ if $4^N\leqslant n\leqslant 4^{N+1}-1$. Let $c_n:=\left[\sqrt n\right]$. Then 
$$\mathbb P\left(B_{4^N}\right)=\prod_{n=4^N}^{4^N+2^N}\mathbb P\left(A_n\right)=\prod_{n=4^N}^{4^N+2^N}\exp\left(-\delta_N\right)=\exp\left(-\left(2^N+1\right)\delta_N\right).$$
Therefore, choosing for example $\delta_N:=\left(2^N+1\right)^{-1}N$, we get that $\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\mathbb P\left(B_n\right)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the example. In the example, the probability of the event B_n is relatively small compared to that of A_n because of the independence of the event $\{A_n\}$. For the non-independent case, will this property still hold?